# Best log to investigate failed startup

Tags: boot, 18.04, login, startup, log

When my system comes back from hibernate, 9 times out of 10, I'm greeted with a permanently black screen that never loads the GUI.  I have to forcefully power off and restart.

What's the log + grep I should use to investigate what is going wrong on my system?